# Rotation of polygon fill symbol using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, polygon, symbology

In ArcMap (ArcGis 10.1) I'm trying to find a way to fill a polygon with a symbol in different orientations. Is it possible?

[image: No images available]
*Example: look at the red semicircles, I would like to do something like that.*

In case it's not: is it possible to associate the rotation of a polygon feature's fill to value in Attribute Table like I can do for points?
[image: No images available]
*Example: rotation of a point feature depending on a column in Attribute Table. Is it possibile to do the same for polygons?*

Comment: Rotation is available in markers and single symbol per polygon (Proportional symbols etc..) not with generic marker fills. You could try ArcScripts or create a mesh of points, intersect with the polygons (to transfer angle) and then draw the points in the polygons.. It would be quite a handy cartographic tool to be able to do this.

Comment: cartographic representations you can give direction of pattern in the fill http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000002q000000

Comment: @Mapperz I have admittedly no experience with representations, but I'm not understanding how the page you link would help. As I read it, it lets you set a control point for the pattern wherever there is an angle over a certain measure and applies only to a line or the outline of the poly, not the fill. Presumably to avoid having a gap or something at a corner, making it somewhat difficult or impossible to tell where the actual vertex/change of direction is (at least based on the example image). I would expect representations can do it somehow, just not sure that applies?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to fill a polygon with symbols on an angle. It cannot be done with Marker symbol type, only with Picture symbol type.

[image]

Even with Picture it applies to the symbol as a whole, meaning you'd need to symbolize on your rotation field and set each one to the angle you want - the angle cannot be read automatically from a field (so far as I know).

Comment: There is also the possibility of creating multiple definitions on the layers to change up the symbology (as Chris has shown above) per grouping (Layer1 Definition Query = Immersione < 50; Layer2 Definition Query = Immersione >= 50 && <100, etc).

Answer (score 2):

The most interesting ideas I found were at
http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=878

> That's not so easy as a fill symbol--you could convert the fill
>   symbols of your landslide layer to representations and then
>   individually rotate the arrow markers within those fill symbols (that
>   might get really tedious).
>
> If you've got an elevation dataset you could do the following:
>
> 1. Use the Aspect tool in either the Spatial or 3D Analyst extensions.  That will produce an output raster with values that
>      represent downhill azimuths. (This assumes that gravity is in play in
>      the sense that flow movement is being derived from an after the fact
>      elevation dataset where downhill movement is assumed to be the path of
>      least resistance.)
> 2. The idea here is to produce a point dataset from the Aspect raster.  But, depending on your map scale you will likely need to
>      reduce the resolution of the Aspect raster before using the Raster to
>      Point tool.  To do that use the Aggregate tool in the Spatial Anaylst.
> 3. Once you have an acceptable outcome from the Raster to Point tool for your map scale (density of points is not too dense or too sparse),
>      then I would add a Short Integer field to the point dataset to have a
>      value of 0 for outside the landslide areas, or 1 for inside the
>      landslide areas.  First calculate all values to 0, and then use Select
>      by Location to select the points inside your landslide areas and
>      calculate that field's value to 1.  That will allow you optionally
>      include (via definition query) or symbolize differently the points
>      outside the landslide areas.
>
> This will result in a more regularly spaced look, like the bottommost
>   of your scans.
>
> Another option, particularly, if you want a more hand rendered look
>   (like the uppermost of your attached scans), you could hand-digitize
>   flow lines and then use cartographic representations on those.  We
>   explain how to set up that kind of symbology on the Mapping Center
>   blog when talking about symbolizing one-way streets.  You could
>   control the spacing and offsets of each flowline's symbol, creating a
>   similarly expressive effect as shown in your attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Use **quantities/graduated colors**.

- Create classification on your rotation field (sth. about 36 classes should be enough).
- Instead of default simple fill symbol use your preferred:  line fill / marker fill / character fill symbol. In each one style you are able to set rotation in manual way.
- For 36 classes increment the rotation angle by 10 degrees for each class (start with 0).

Its rather tedious work but it should work.

As a result you should get a pretty good approximation of your map.